# Open php page in html div using javascript

Tags: php, html, mysql

I open php/mysql page in div html using this code:-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#test").click(function(){
     $("#section2").hide();
    $("#section1").load("home/header.php").show();

 });
 });
```

When I press upload the page disappears.

Here is the page after I loaded the php page:-

[image: Here the page after i loaded the php page]

Here is the page after I press upload to mysql:

[image: here the page after i press upload to mysql]

I use this function

```
function saveimage($name,$image) {
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","***","***");
    mysqli_select_db($con,'images');

  // $qry="insert into images(name,image) values ('$name','$image')";
  $qry="UPDATE images SET image='$image',name = '$name' WHERE id=1";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
    if($result){
      echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Image Uploaded</div>';     
    } else {

     // echo   mysqli_error($con); 
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Image Not Uploaded</div>';   
    }

   header("location:header.php");
    exit;
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: What is the function of the upload button?

Comment: don't post code as picture. rather post it as text

Comment: done i posted the function

Comment: i didn't post code as pictures , the picture show the page before and after i press upload

Comment: It might be helpful to have the relevant HTML code as well.